# JQuery vs GetElementById

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something since yesterday, and I'm really stuck. 
Here is what « works » for now :

```
<h1 onclick="functionToggle(<?php echo "'".$base."'" ?>)"> <?php  echo $base ?></h1>
```

which echo :

```
<h1 onclick="functionToggle('helpers')"> helpers</h1>
```

And I have a div like this one :

```
<div id="helpers" class="hidden">
    <div class="fichier">audio_extensions March 02 2013 23:35:36.</div>
    <div class="fichier">ebook_extensions March 02 2013 19:42:55.</div>
    <div class="fichier">movie_extensions March 02 2013 20:28:01.</div>
    <div class="fichier">zip_extensions March 02 2013 19:50:21</div>
</div>
```

The thing is : With this function, in JS :

```
<script>
    function functionToggle(elem){
        etat=document.getElementById(elem).style.display;
        if(etat=="none"){
            document.getElementById(elem).style.display="block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(elem).style.display="none";
        }
    }

 </script>
```

This works. I just wanted to know how to do this with JQuery ? I have tried something like this :

```
<script>
    function functionToggle(elem){
        $("#elem").toggle();
    }
 </script>
```

and many other combinaison, but it doesn't work. I don't have any error, it simply doesn't work.

If you have a solution :)

Comment: `$("#"+elem).toggle();`

Comment: you better put your jQuery code inside document.ready() function . It ensure us that this script will be executed after all the objects have been created .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the actual id of your element.

```
<script>
    function functionToggle(elem) {
       $('#' + elem).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: OMG Thank you ! I can't figure out why I didn't think of that… Well thank you again !

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#elem").toggle(); // which find the element with id "elem"
```

should be

```
$("#"+elem).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the string `#elem` to jQuery. You need to pass `"#" + elem`